# iframe scroll event not fired when using srcdoc=

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an iframe to display an html document. I need to detect scroll events in the iframe. Using src= works fine, but srcdoc= does not fire the scroll event.

HTML:

```
<iframe id="TermsConditionsText" srcdoc="﻿<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC &quot;-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN&quot; &quot;http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd&quot;><html xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml&quot;><head><meta http-equiv=&quot;Content-Type&quot; content=&quot;application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8&quot; /><title></title></head><body><div class=&quot;Section0&quot;> ... </div></body></html>" class="form-control" style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 600px;"></iframe>
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var termsWereScrolled = false;

    $("#TermsConditionsText").scroll(function () {
        if (termsWereScrolled) return true;

        if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() + 2 >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            termsWereScrolled = true;
        }
    });
});
```

Does iframe trigger scroll events when using srcdoc= ?

Comment: The frame's scroll event happens inside the iframe, not in the parent window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does iframe trigger scroll events when using srcdoc= ?

Yes it does trigger scroll events when using `srcdoc`.

The thing with `iframe` is that it is a new window and it has its own document; so, you have to attach the event to its document not to the element itself. Nonetheless, all you have to do is query the `iframe`'s contents like `$("#TermsConditionsText").contents()` to attach the event. Check this out:

```
var iframeContents = $("#TermsConditionsText").contents();

$(iframeContents).scroll(function () {
    console.log('scroll');

    var html = $(this)[0].scrollingElement;
    console.log('scrollHeight', html.scrollHeight);
});
```

Comment: This does work! The code above is intended to set `termsWereScrolled` to true when the iframe is scrolled all the way to bottom. It looks like `$(this)[0].scrollHeight` is now undefined. Do you also know why this isn't working right? Thanks!

Comment: `HTMLDocument` doesn't have `scrollHeight` but it does have `$(this)[0].scrollingElement` which is the `html` element which by the way have the `$(this)[0].scrollingElement.scrollHeight`.